# Bitmapped symbols using PDFLatex

Tags: pdftex

I'm having a problem when rendering my Latex code to PDF when using PDFLatex. My problem is that, when I render the code, some math symbols like the parentheses appear bitmapped, with bad quality and I don't see where the problem is. These are some examples of what I see:
[image]

[image]

These are the packages that i'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{physics}


\title{Determinació de la constant de gravitació universal G}
\author{Carlos Gómez Cayuela}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate some help with this. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Your TeX installation misses the PFB version of the `mathabx` fonts. Are you with MiKTeX on Windows, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for answering.Yes, I am using MiKTeX on Windows. How can I install that PFB version?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to work it out! That was the problem.